# Can't connect tableau with a remote SQL server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, tableau

I stored my database in my Windows notebook and Tableau in my MacBook. I tried to connect Tableau with the remote SQL Server, I entered the name of my server and the user name and password that I gave the access privileges to my database. When I clicked sign in, it always pop-up a warning that

> Unable to connect to the server. 
>   Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the SQL Server logs to find out what exactly is the problem. If you are indeed connected to the right SQL Server instance, any authentication failure will be logged.

[image: SQL Server log]

Another alternative to Windows authentication is to log in to SQL Server with a `runas` account

[image: Authenticate with runas account]